# Ruby refuse to close connection in net/telnet and gave error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, telnet

I am using the code below to access our router via telnet but in the end of commands it is retrieve strange error.

```
require 'net/telnet'

USER = 'admin'
PASS = "12c@cddf"

local = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "10.10.13.3",
                        
                             "Binmode" => true,
                             "Output_log" => "output_log.log",
                             'Prompt' => /[$%#,:] \z/n
                            )

  sleep 3
  local.cmd("admin"){
    |c| print c
      local.cmd("12c@cddf"){
        |c| print c
          local.cmd("enable"){
            |c| print
              local.cmd("quit"){
                |c| print c
                  local.cmd("y"){
                    |c| print c
                  }
              }
          }   
      }
      
  }
local.close
```

The Last response is below, how can i solve this ?
is the wrong with cmd using should i use something else ?

```
  Configuration console exit, please retry to log on
/Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:560:in `readpartial': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:560:in `waitfor'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:694:in `cmd'
    from home.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:694:in `block in cmd'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:593:in `waitfor'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:694:in `cmd'
    from home.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:694:in `block in cmd'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:593:in `waitfor'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:694:in `cmd'
    from home.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:694:in `block in cmd'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:593:in `waitfor'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:694:in `cmd'
    from home.rb:21:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:694:in `block in cmd'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:593:in `waitfor'
    from /Users/sedcvf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/telnet.rb:694:in `cmd'
    from home.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

How can i clear that error ?

Comment: You are doing the `close` inside a `local.cmd` block. This looks wrong to me. I would close it after the block has finished.

Comment: I gave it try and i got on same error

Comment: Then at least update the code in your question to reflect your changes.

Comment: It's ok. The server is closing the connection, as you have asked it to. Your Ruby code is surprised by that. You either have to close the connection after getting the response to `enable` with `local.close`, or handle the exception.

Comment: Also, you don't have to wrap subsequent messages in a nested way. https://github.com/ruby/net-telnet#check-a-pop-server-to-see-if-you-have-mail
The subsequent message won't get sent before you receive the response for the previous one.

Comment: Also, if you don't care about the response, you can skip the block, e.g. `local.cmd('admin')`.